# BASH - grepping for a value stored in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, grep

So I am trying to use grep on a Windows Registry hive, through the following command:

```
grep -i -A6 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\.SYSTEM\.ControlSet001\.Services\.atapi RegistryEntries/ControlSet001.reg | grep Start | tail -c 4
```

This works perfectly fine and returns the value that I am interested in, which is 000

However, when I attempt to store "atapi" in a variable as shown below:

```
x="atapi"
grep -i -A6 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\.SYSTEM\.ControlSet001\.Services.\.$x RegistryEntries/ControlSet001.reg | grep Start | tail -c 4
```

I get nothing, I have also tried using

```
x=atapi
```

without quotes and have still had no luck, I am pretty new to BASH so I could very well be missing something simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part seems to be problem in your regex:

```
Services.\.$x
```

Since it is matching literal dot after text `Services` and **any character**.

Remove extra dot after `Services` and use your grep command with quotes:

```
x="atapi"
grep -i -A6 "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\.SYSTEM\.ControlSet001\.Services\.$x" RegistryEntries/ControlSet001.reg | grep Start | tail -c 4
```